# How to add multiple columns in reset_index from a pandas- series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Am having a pandas series & i need to show it's elements in columnar fashion embedded in an email body with HTML.Hence tried below snippet. It worked for me initially with two columns, but now i have three columns to display. Here is code-

```
a = max_compare.rename_axis('Metric').reset_index(name='Yesterday').to_html()
```

Here max_compare is series with below output-

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Metric</th>
      <th>Yesterday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>GSV</td>
      <td>4424180.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Units</td>
      <td>7463.0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now i am having another element to be shown in column. Tried below code snippet, but got exception.

```
a =max_compare.rename_axis('Metric').reset_index(name=['Yesterday'],[L30 average]).to_html()
```

Current Output in HTML
Output- [image: Added Image for current & expected output in HTML table format]

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not provide any data sample nor expected result, I do not know exactly what you want to do. However, this is how to reset a MultiIndex.

> `level` : int, str, tuple, or list, default None
>   Only remove the given levels from the index. Removes all levels by default

[Link to the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# Paste the text by using of triple-quotes to span String literals on multiple lines
zz = """index grade   class   numgrade  numyear
0   A      Senior        12         4
1   A      Junior        12         3
2   A      Junior        12         3
3   A      Senior        12         4
4   A      Junior        12         3
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), delim_whitespace=True)
df.set_index(['index', 'grade'], inplace=True)
# Reset the two levels
df.reset_index(level=(0,1))
```

### Edit

The same method can be used with `Series`. But Reseting a `MultiIndex` of a `Series` will convert it back to a `DataFrame` since `Series`, by definition, have only one column (a value) and an index. In consequence, I think you should use `DataFrame` if you want to deal with more than one column.

```
# Paste the text by using of triple-quotes to span String literals on multiple lines
zz = """index grade class
0   A      Senior
1   A      Junior
2   A      Junior
3   A      Senior
4   A      Junior
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), delim_whitespace=True)
df.set_index(['index', 'grade'], inplace=True)

# Creating a series with a multiIndex
se = df.iloc[:,0]
print(type(se))
# Reseting index also works for Series.
# In case of MultiIndex, Series will be converted back 
# to a DataFrame since Series, by definition, have 
# only one column and an index
se.reset_index(level=(0,1))

# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
#    index grade   class
# 0      0     A  Senior
# 1      1     A  Junior
# 2       2     A  Junior
# 3      3     A  Senior
# 4      4     A  Junior
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'. Not using dataframe, having Series type.